# Why does PodSpelling complain about an ignored word if it's part of a file name?

Tags: perl, perl-pod

[PodSpelling](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Documentation::PodSpelling) (run via Perlcritic) complains about "html" even though I've added this to the `stopwords`:

```perl
=for stopwords html

=head2 some function

Generates an index.html page.

=cut
```

This gets:

```
robert@saaz:~$ perlcritic --brutal  test.pl | grep html
Check the spelling in your POD: html at line 1, column 1.  See page 148 of PBP.  (Severity: 1)
```

(I pipe the output through `grep` to ignore the other complaints in this minimal example that are unrelated to spelling.)

If I change the POD to either use `C<index.html>` or `F<index.html>`, or rewrite it as `a .html file`, or add "index.html" as a stopword, the spell checker is happy. The first makes sense to me (don't check code snippets or file names), but I don't see what the big difference between "index.html" and ".html" is.

Does it work with `=for stopwords index.html` because it ignores the dot when it's next to white space? I'm just guessing here, though.

Why does my `stopword html` not work for "index.html" and how can I fix this if I don't want to use `C<...>` or `F<...>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors of Pod::Wordlist implemented it that way. They wanted to make sure that abbreviations like e.g. "*e.g.*" will be passed to the spellchecker as a whole.
Since the splitting and stripping of stopwords is done before the wordlist gets passed to the spellchecker you can't have both. On the other hand the default spellchecker is `aspell`. Here it seems to me, that abbreviations pass the check no matter if they are split on periods or not.

So you can change Pod/Wordlist.pm like this:

```
#line 129
sub _strip_a_word {
    my ($self, $word) = @_;
    my $remainder;

    # try word as-is, including possible hyphenation vs stoplist
    if ($self->is_stopword($word) ) {
        $remainder = '';
    }

        # check individual parts of hyphenated or period separated word,
        # keep whatever isn't a stopword as individual words
        # aspell will accept split words for abbreviations as well
        # 'e.g' passes like 'e g' does
    elsif ( $word =~ /-|\./ ) {
            my @keep;
            for my $part ( split /-|\./, $word ) {
                push @keep, $part if ! $self->is_stopword( $part );
            }
            $remainder = join(" ", @keep) if @keep;
    }
    # otherwise, we just keep it
    else {
        $remainder = $word;
    }
    return $remainder;
}
```